# lost data when i refresh the page react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi I want to show a page with `id` which is a form from a list of forms, it works but when I refresh the page I lost data and get an error

this is the code

```
function FormFinal() {
    const { id } = useParams();

    const forms = useSelector((state) => state.forms.data)

    const specificForm = forms.find((elem) => elem._id === id)
```

and this is how I'm trying to show data

```
<div className='title-compagny'> Entreprise: {specificForm.compagnyName </div>
```

this is the route on my api:

```js
formRouter.get('/:formId', formController.getForm)
```

and the route on the front:

```js
   <Route exact path="/final-form/:id">
    <FormFinal /></Route>
```

on refresh I'm getting this message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'compagnyName' of undefined`

Comment: On refresh you have lost `id`, put a log after this line `const { id } = useParams();` and confirm it. As you don't have `id` so the array filter method doesn't return any value.

Comment: The `id` match param is based on the currently matched path, so what is causing the URL to change? Or perhaps the `state.forms.data` is lost? Can you include your routing code that is rendering this component? Confirm which of `id` or `forms` array is changed after reloading the page?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz it shows me the id of the forms even when i refresh

Comment: @DrewReese i added the code

Comment: @MounaSis are you using any async call to get the data ?

Comment: @MounaSis if possible create a jsfiddle and provide that link so that we can understand the actual scenario

Comment: When and where are you requesting the form data? And yes, if you're able to create a *running* codesandbox (or similar) that we can live debug in we may be better able to help.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz which code should i share? I’m not used to using jsdiddle

Comment: codesandbox or jsdiddle is a live debug environment, it is helpful for such debugging

Comment: @MounaSis you have to share the same code which is not working fine

Comment: @MayankPandeyz sorry i couldn't share it because all the files are linked and there are too many files, can i resolve the problem if i set the id in the localstorage?

Comment: I think the issue is not related to id, I think its related to async axios call. The data is coming from axios call right ?

Comment: yes i use axios to get data (all the forms), ans id params to display each form with his ID